# Apache HTTPD does not list all files in directory

Tags: apache-httpd, apache-virtualhost

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
Server built:   Nov 16 2020 16:18:20
```

When I go to browser and type IP/result I do not see all the files in directory.

```
Alias /result "/var/geojson"
<Directory "/var/geojson">
    Options +Indexes
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Does your Apache configuration include any `IndexIgnore` directives, either directly or by way of inclusions?

Comment: No, it does not have `IndexIgnore` anywhere

Comment: My first guess would be SELinux. Try switching that off and restarting apache. If it is the cause of the issue then you're on your on fixing the SELinux permissions.

Comment: SELinux was the culprit. Why does some files whould be "selected" to not to be listed by Apache though...

Comment: Post that as an answer

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure your vhost to show forbidden files with the directive `IndexOptions +ShowForbidden` inside your `<Directory>` declaration:

```
...
Options +Indexes
IndexOptions +ShowForbidden 
...
```

Restart `apache` server and now you should be able to see all the files.

Comment: Adding this line just made page *.gifs not getting loaded. Other than that there was no difference.

Comment: Added that info to the question.

Comment: @user435421 you could try adding the directive `IndexIgnoreReset ON` and see what happens.

Comment: @user435421 wait, it's `+ShowForbidden` not `ShowForbidden`.

Comment: Tried `IndexIgnoreReset ON` and +ShowForbidden. But result is sadly the same. I have tried to make `result` to look to different directory (`/var/log`) and it displayed all files and folders that were both visible and invisible

Comment: @user435421 dumb question maybe, but did you restart the server after the changes?

Comment: Of course _____